# logistics of large conference scheduling

Tags: schedule, constraint-programming

I have to schedule a conference, there is 6 class everyday and more than 10 lecturer,for 14days. some lecturer are available some days, some are not, some prefer some specific day or classess and some days they are off

i googled it so much but couldn't find good material to learn about it.
i want to learn it ground up, it means if i need to learn constrain programming it's okey for me, because i don't have any background about it.

i'm looking for learning material, book and any suggestion about this. someplace in stackoverflow i read genetic algorithm it's good for it but no one was sure about it. 
because it's one of the most easy topic that i have to face, and i will face more hard solution in future, i have to learn from basic, new task from my manager and i have to face it.

i appreciate if you suggest any book, site, paper and sources to learn or share with me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[OptaPlanner](http://www.optaplanner.org/) (open source, Java) is used for conference and course scheduling. The download contains the code of a complete course scheduling example called "curriculum course", which is also documented in the reference manual.

As for other sites, you might find the ITC2007 timetabling competition interesting.